Optimizing performance in Pine Script, when using request.security, v6, using conditional local blocks and dynamical calls == true
I have a performance intensive function that I would like to run in a higher timeframe context (request.security).
The function does not need to run every bar, and definitely not every realtime tick.
... and so I was hoping that with the release of pine v6, that I could place the request.security inside a local block / condition ... to allow for the (heavy) function to be called much less often.
When I did this, the pine profiler indicated that the request.security call was running regardless of the local block condition that it was embedded within.  ie. it was running on every bar (and tick) even when the condition should prevent it.
I'm confused as to whether this is expected behaviour, or not.

This is what I tried.
indicator("My script", dynamic_requests = true)
out = 0.
if close%2 == 0  //some arbitrary condition
    out := request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", close)
plot(out)

To keep it simple, I have replaced the call to myVeryBigFunction() with a call to "close"... it doesn't make any difference to the outcome/issue.
The value of "out" responds correctly.   It is only ever set when the condition (close%2 == 0) is true.  As expected.
But.  The pine profiler, shows that the line with request.security has run on every bar (and each realtime tick).
I don't need it to run every tick (hence trying to put the call inside a condition).

This is (according to the manual) not what I expected:

Scripts that allow dynamic requests do not restrict the execution of request.() calls to the global scope. They can call request.() functions directly within the scopes of conditional structures and loops, meaning that each request.*() instance in the code can activate zero, one, or several times on each script execution.

However, I logged a support request, and got the response:

Calculations using the request.security() function are performed based on the data from the requested chart or timeframe before the main script executes. These calculations are independent of local conditions or the placement of calls within logical blocks on the main script and the request is processed regardless, including any log functions and their results.

So.  Now I'm confused.

I want to activate my request.* call "zero, one, or several times on each script execution" in order to save performance.
Can I do that? ... or will it just run anyways? ... should I even be trying to do this? .... ultimately I plan to run a lot of fairly heavy code, and I want it to load, and return values, as quickly as possible.   Time is money (and of course, to be nice to TV).
Thanks in advance for any assistance.  Appreciated.

Sorry for the incorrect information provided in the user manual. We will ensure it is updated promptly.
Please note that even with dynamic security, the execution will occur on each bar or tick.

Thanks.  I feared this might be.
I guess what I will need to do is alter the contents of MyVeryBigFunction() that I am planning to run in the different context(s)
.... so that it runs the heavy code when the conditions call for it ... and otherwise returns without doing the heavy work.
Does that seem like a good approach to you?

You need to put a value with "series string" type into ticker or timeframe parameters for make request.security really dynamic. For example:
//@version=6
indicator("My script", dynamic_requests = true)
out = 0.
tf = ""
if close%2 == 0  //some arbitrary condition
    tf := "15"
if tf!=""
    out := request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tf, close)
plot(out)


When I run this code, the profiler indicates that the line with request.security, runs on every tick.

Maybe this is because the expression close%2 == 0 is true on every tick? :-D

If you replace close%2 == 0 to close < 0 you will see 0 calls in the profiler.

That is not correct.   You see a call in the profiler on every tick, regardless of the condition.   If you place a log.info call inside the condition --- you can see also that the log is populated on each tick.   This is consistent with what TV told me in my support request... but the pine script manual appeared to contract this (TV have said they will update the manual).


Calculations using the request.security() function are performed based
on the data from the requested chart or timeframe before the main
script executes. These calculations are independent of local
conditions or the placement of calls within logical blocks on the main
script and the request is processed regardless, including any log
functions and their results.

The response I received in my support request to TV (see quote above) is correct.
Star Lucky commented above:

Sorry for the incorrect information provided in the user manual. We will ensure it is updated promptly. Please note that even with dynamic security, the execution will occur on each bar or tick.

Tradingview are going to update the pine script manual.
The reality is that while you can "dynamically" use request.security, by using series parameters, and by placing the request.security call inside a block/condition ..... the actual EXECUTION of the request.security call will happen on every tick regardless of conditions.
We can see that this is true, by including a log entry in the function passed to request.security, as commented by tradingview here:

These calculations are independent of local conditions or the placement of calls within logical blocks on the main script and the request is processed regardless, including any log functions and their results.

f()=>
    log.info("this is log")
    close

... and calling it from another context within a condition.
out = 0.
if close%2 == 0
    out := request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "15", f())
else
    out := 0
plot(out)

... and we see that while out is set to the (15m) value of close only when close%2 == 0 ... that the log is populated on every realtime tick even when close%2 != 0
